# How to write a Makefile in Windows to compile a Latex document using a loop

Tags: pdftex, windows, loops, makefile

I need to write several documents that are fairly close to each other, i.e.same structure of header/footer, call a common set of forms. 
I wrote a Main.tex document with a set of \if\x 1 { my document content}\fi to control the content of each document. My variable "x" is also used as information in the header.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, ,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\newcommand\x{1}

\rhead{My document \x}
\lhead{Left header}
\chead{version:1.0}
\lfoot{\thepage\ ~of~\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\if\x 1 {
  \include{FrontPage}
  \include{FormA}
  \include{FormB}
  \include{FormC}
}\fi

\if\x 2 {  
  \include{FrontPage}
  \include{FormA}
  \include{FormB}
  \include{FormB}
}\fi

\if\x 3 {   
  \include{FrontPage}
  \include{FromA}
  \include{FromC}
  \include{FormC}
}\fi 
\end{document}
```

On Linux (Ubuntu), I wrote a makefile:

```
SHELL   = /bin/sh

all:
    make tex
    make clean

tex:
    for number in 1 2 3; do \
        echo $$number ; \
        pdflatex -no-pdf --jobname=Mydocument-No-$$number "\newcommand\x{$$number} \input{main.tex}"  ; \
        pdflatex --jobname=Mydocument-No-$$number "\newcommand\x{$$number} \input{main.tex}"  ; \
    done;\

help:
    echo "USAGE: make [all/tex/clean]"

clean:
    rm -f *.aux *.dvi *.idx *.ilg *.ind *.log *.nav *.out *.snm *.xdv *.toc *~
```

Which call my main.tex file 3 times, sending the value of x to my latex document, and also renaming the output. At the end I get 3 pdf. I only have to write "make" in the Konsole of Kile to make it work.

Unfortunately, I now have to transfer this process under Windows - 
Any idea on how to write the equivalent of my makefile in Windows ?
I have TeXnicCenter and Texmaker installed.

Comment: there are of course make implementations for windows, or you could write a loop in dos cmd syntax or use Lua (and the texlua that comes with tex) for a cross-platform alternative.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158419/how-to-run-makefile-in-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this, by writing a makefile.bat for Windows as suggested by David Carlisle:

```
FOR %%i IN (1,2,3) DO (
echo %%i
pdflatex --jobname=Mydocument-No-%%i "\newcommand\x{%%i} \input{main.tex}"  
pdflatex --jobname=Mydocument-No-%%i "\newcommand\x{%%i} \input{main.tex}" 
)
DEL *.aux *.log *.backup
```

I run it by double clicking on the file.